# I can't install eth-brownie on windows

Tags: python, brownie, pipx

*I also installed microsoft c++ 14.... but i really don't know how to get around this*
*Here is the error:*

```
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    C:\Users\aiatu\.local\pipx\logs\cmd_2022-12-23_22.25.32_pip_errors.log

pip failed to build packages:
    bitarray
    cytoolz
    yarl

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    cytoolz/dicttoolz.c(209): fatal error C1083: Non Š possibile aprire il file inclusione: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
    yarl/_quoting_c.c(196): fatal error C1083: Non Š possibile aprire il file inclusione: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

Answer (score 0):

Once again, here answering my own queston.
*I had python 3.11.1, i deleted this python version and installed 3.10.9. and then i installed brownie via:* `pip install eth-brownie`